# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject fails due to unexpected characters

Tags: c#, json.net

I am getting a JSON encoded string from a webrequest.

the string comes back like this

```cs
"{\"key\":\"value\"}"
```

when I try to parse that with  `DeserializeObject` from JsonConvert I get

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

the code I'm using so far looks like this

```cs
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address));
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
string response;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string stream = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "");
    stream = stream.Replace("\\", "");
    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(stream);
}
```

obviously the `replace("\\", "")` does not do the trick, and I really don't want to have to do this since it is an unclean way of converting the string to what I need. how do I get rid of the `\` in the string?

Comment: Are you sure the string *really* has backslashes in, or is that what you see in the debugger?

Comment: How do you know that the string that comes back is like this?

Comment: this is from the debugger in visual studio.

Comment: Because if it is exactly like this, it is ***not*** a "JSON encoded string".

Comment: When I ran the address through postman the response looked normal, {"key":"value"}

Comment: So, if this question is now answered, you might want to close it.  Otherwise, if there is still a problem, then you might want to elaborate as to what the problem really is.  Because the string appears to be all right and in no need to have any quotes removed from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stream` string contains a JSON object and you're trying to deserialize it as a string (`...DeserializeObject<  string  >(stream)`), hence the exception. So you're not getting a "JSON encoded *string*", you're getting a "JSON encoded *object*".

You need to decide what you want to have in `response`:

- If it's some JSON for further processing, just set the `response` to `stream`.
- If it should contain an object hierarchy, define the necessary classes and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>()`. Alternatively, you may consider using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm).
- If it should contain some value extracted from that JSON definition, ["LINQ to JSON"](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) may prove quite helpful:

  ```
  response = (string)JObject.Parse(stream)["key"];
  ```